# SQL Server 2005 Transaction Level and Stored Procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, t-sql, transactions

If I use the command `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` and then execute a stored procedure using the `EXEC storedProcedureName` on the same context, will the stored procedure use the transaction level stated previously or will use a default one?

If I want to force every stored procedure to use on transaction level do I have to include at the top of the code the same statement (`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`)?

PS.: the system is built on top of .NET 2.0 and proprietary third party products with limitations, hence the need of these workarounds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The stored procedure will use the transaction isolation in effect when called.

If the stored procedure itself sets an explicit isolation level this will be reset when the stored procedure exits.

(Edit: Just checked and this is [contrary to what BOL says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) "... it remains set for that connection until it is explicitly changed" but can be seen from the below)

```
CREATE PROC CheckTransLevel
AS
DECLARE @Result varchar(20)

SELECT @Result = CASE transaction_isolation_level 
                        WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncomitted' 
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Readcomitted' 
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable' 
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable' 
                        WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' 
                  END 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
WHERE session_id = @@SPID

PRINT @Result

GO
CREATE PROC SetRCTransLevel
AS
PRINT 'Enter: SetRCTransLevel'
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
EXEC CheckTransLevel
PRINT 'Exit: SetRCTransLevel'
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

EXEC CheckTransLevel

EXEC SetRCTransLevel

EXEC CheckTransLevel
```

Results

```
ReadUncomitted
Enter: SetRCTransLevel
Readcomitted
Exit: SetRCTransLevel
ReadUncomitted
```

Comment: +1 This blows my mind... I could have sworn that I actually saw SQL Server functioning how BOL says; I had an issue where one stored procedure upped the isolation to serializable, and then other stored procedures were impacted, but I guess that maybe it was the application that was holding on to that isolation level and not SQL Server.

Comment: The documentation actually does describe this behavior (it is in a later paragraph, unfortunately, and it may have been added in the intervening ~6.5 years): If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset to the level in effect when the object was invoked.