# SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL Scope on stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure and I do not want any locking through out the script. I am sure that I need to state "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED" in the beginning of the script. But I am not sure how to start after the statement. One of the example from Microsoft show that start with "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and end with "END TRANSACTION". There is someone who starts without any  BEGIN and END statement after "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED". Please, suggest me for the right way of using "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL" statement to achieve my goal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216(v=sql.80).aspx

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM publishers
SELECT * FROM authors
...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

[SQL Server: how to set default isolation level for the entire stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975936/sql-server-how-to-set-default-isolation-level-for-the-entire-stored-procedure)

```
BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
 -- will a transaction level for a atomic transaction created by SQL Server for this statement be READ COMMITTED 
SELECT * FROM T
END
```

Comment: The second code snippet is the write way to use in Stored Procs.It must be on beginning of sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are ok

[Transaction scope in a stored procedure, from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql)

> If you issue SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL in a stored procedure or
>   trigger, when the object returns control the isolation level is reset
>   to the level in effect when the object was invoked. For example, if
>   you set REPEATABLE READ in a batch, and the batch then calls a stored
>   procedure that sets the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE, the isolation
>   level setting reverts to REPEATABLE READ when the stored procedure
>   returns control to the batch.